# Simple Masonry Script won't run in IE8

Tags: internet-explorer, runtime-error, jquery-masonry

when I set this unordered list:

```
<ul class="lay5" id="list">
<li class="grid1 vcard ... some more classes" data-gmapping="{..some JSON...}"><a href="link.html"><h2>Aachen</h2><p>Anzahl Museen: 17<br>Keine Ausstellung</p></a></li>
</ul>
```

to be re-ordered by masonry in this way:

```
$('#list').masonry({
columnWidth: 195,
itemSelector: '.grid1'
});
```

it works fine on Safari, Firefox, Chrome, but on IE 8 I get the error

```
»Invalid procedure call or argument«.
```

According to the message, the error occurs at line 1124 char 5 on masonry.pkgd.js
But, in this line there is no procedure call.

Furthermore, IE puts all my li elements to position top=0 left=0.

Does anyone know how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Found out that I had picked up some invisible elements, trying again with clean code.